# AngularJS Promise best practise for chaining $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ecmascript-5

I'm new to writing and using promises and I'd like some advice. I have to chain my promises because some functions can only be run after others. I did used to handle this with a LOT of callback functions, which looked very messy and confusing. But with the chaining I'm doing... it's starting to look a bit messy again and I'm wondering whether I'm doing this correctly...

```
    function calcNetPriceSaleCharge(theItem) {
    var setInitialChargeAmount = miscSaleSvc.getInitialCharge(theItem);
    var setDiscountAmount = miscSaleSvc.getDiscountAmount(theItem);

    $q
        .all([setInitialChargeAmount, setDiscountAmount])
        .then(function(values) {
            theItem.initialchargeamount = values[0];
            theItem.initialdiscountamount = values[1];
        })
        .then(function() {
            var setActualCharge = miscSaleSvc.getActualCharge(theItem);
            var setVat = miscSaleSvc.setVat(theItem);
            $q
                .all([setActualCharge, setVat])
                .then(function(values) {
                    theItem.actualcharge = values[0];
                    theItem.vat = values[1];
                })
                .then(function() {
                    var setTotal = miscSaleSvc.getSaleTotal(theItem);

                    $q
                        .all([setTotal])
                        .then(function(values) {
                            theItem.total = values[0];
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

this does work but im not sure I'm going about this the right way! An example function that is being called is this...

```
srv.getInitialCharge = function(theItem) {
    //set up the deferred var
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var initialchargeamount = parseFloat(theItem.normalperiodcharge * theItem.quantity);

    if (isNaN(initialchargeamount)) {
        deferred.reject("Error when calculating Initial Charge Amount.");
    } else {
        //set up the failed result
        deferred.resolve(initialchargeamount);
    }

    //return the promise
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: A slightly more compact way would be to use `async/await`. Also you dont need to nest Promises. You can just return something like `$q.all()` from a callback and continue the outer chain.

Comment: http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: @Sirko `async/await` uses ES6 promises which are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its $q promises. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Remember that you can use `$q.reject` and `$q.when` to create rejected/fulfilled promises. The is no need to use `$q.defer()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a little callback hell which is exactly what Promises try to avoid. Remeber that you can also return a Promise inside `then` block to handle it further with `then` in the same chain of calls:

```
function calcNetPriceSaleCharge(theItem) {
  var setInitialChargeAmount = miscSaleSvc.getInitialCharge(theItem);
  var setDiscountAmount = miscSaleSvc.getDiscountAmount(theItem);

  $q.all([setInitialChargeAmount, setDiscountAmount])
    .then(function(values) {
      theItem.initialchargeamount = values[0];
      theItem.initialdiscountamount = values[1];
    })
    .then(function() {
      var setActualCharge = miscSaleSvc.getActualCharge(theItem);
      var setVat = miscSaleSvc.setVat(theItem);
      return $q.all([setActualCharge, setVat]);
    })
    .then(function(values) {
      theItem.actualcharge = values[0];
      theItem.vat = values[1];
    })
    .then(function() {
      var setTotal = miscSaleSvc.getSaleTotal(theItem);
      return $q.all([setTotal]);
    })
    .then(function(values) {
      theItem.total = values[0];
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

another variation:

```
function calcNetPriceSaleCharge(theItem) {
  var setInitialChargeAmount = miscSaleSvc.getInitialCharge(theItem);
  var setDiscountAmount = miscSaleSvc.getDiscountAmount(theItem);

  return $q
    .all([setInitialChargeAmount, setDiscountAmount])
    .then(function(values) {
      theItem.initialchargeamount = values[0];
      theItem.initialdiscountamount = values[1];
    })
    .then(function() {
      var setActualCharge = miscSaleSvc.getActualCharge(theItem);
      var setVat = miscSaleSvc.setVat(theItem);
      return $q.all([setActualCharge, setVat]);
    })
    .then(function(values) {
      theItem.actualcharge = values[0];
      theItem.vat = values[1];
    })
    .then(function() {
      var setTotal = miscSaleSvc.getSaleTotal(theItem);
      return $q.all([setTotal]);
    })
    .then(function(values) {
      return (theItem.total = values[0]);
    });
}

calcNetPriceSaleCharge(something)
  .then(function(finalValue) {
    console.log(finalValue);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: oooh this looks much nicer! I'll give it a go :) thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly and my code is looking happy again :D

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness sake a version using `async/await` syntax (Note, that this might [not be available for older browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions)). For better readability the variable naming should be changed, however.

```
async function calcNetPriceSaleCharge(theItem) {
  try {
    const setInitialChargeAmount = miscSaleSvc.getInitialCharge(theItem),
          setDiscountAmount = miscSaleSvc.getDiscountAmount(theItem);

    const values0 = await Promise.all( [setInitialChargeAmount, setDiscountAmount] );

    theItem.initialchargeamount = values0[0];
    theItem.initialdiscountamount = values0[1];

    const setActualCharge = miscSaleSvc.getActualCharge(theItem),
          setVat = miscSaleSvc.setVat(theItem);

    const values1 = await Promise.all( [setActualCharge, setVat] );

    theItem.actualcharge = values1[0];
    theItem.vat = values1[1];

    const values2 = await miscSaleSvc.getSaleTotal(theItem);

    theItem.total = values2;

  } catch ( e ) {
    console.log( e );
  }
}
```

Comment: is this possible when writing ES5?

Comment: @Janey No, not without a transpiler. That's the reason for my note about "older" browsers.